# fragment from fragment activity calls startactivityforresult but notifydatasetchanged does not work

Tags: android, notifydatasetchanged, startactivityforresult

i have a fragment activity 'feedlistActivity' inside this i have a fragment 'myPostFragment' this fragment contains a listView, and from that fragment i called startActivityForResult to start a new activity 'MyActivity'.

MyActivity.class

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtra("POST_OBJECT", postData);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                    finish();
```

MyPostFragment.class

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        editIntent.putExtra("EDIT_POST", postDetailsData);
        startActivity(editIntent);
        break;    

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ADD_EDIT_POST ) {

                if (data != null && data.hasExtra("POST_OBJECT")) {
                    PostDetailsData postData = (PostDetailsData) data
                            .getSerializableExtra("POST_OBJECT");

                    if (postData != null) {
                        myPostFeedList.add(postData);
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        setAdapter();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void setAdapter() {
    // if (postAdapter == null) {
    postAdapter = new PostListAdapter(context, myPostFeedList);
    postAdapter.setSwipeOptionClickedListner(this);
    myPostfeedListView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // } else {
    // postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // }

}
```

FeedlistActivity.class

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

My Problem is that above code does not works for me when i call 'notifyDatasetChanged' and list does not get refreshed instantly

Comment: your adapter might be implemented in wrong way. It might store data in wrong variable.

Comment: can u post setAdapter() ?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Raghavendra , i have added my setadapter method, this method i also used to initialy load data. it works ok at that time

Comment: ewerything looks more-less ok. Please try to debug line-by-line to see if you are using correct values

Comment: Check this, You may find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: everything in above gets executed when i applied debugger but still data does not get refreshed

Comment: hey after lot of search i found that data gets added on bottom of arraylist  listview. so can i add that on top of list? please help

Answer (score 0):

You should debug step by step in order to find whether the function **`"postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()"`** is executed.

Comment: If the resultCode doesn't matches ,the following code can't be executed surely.

Comment: now i have made some changes in code now everything works ok, the postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() also getting called but only listview does not get refreshed

Comment: You can try to check whether or not the class of PostListAdapter is writed correctedly.

Comment: hello after lot of search i found that the listview got notified but the data gets added on the bottom of arraylist listview. what is solution on that? can you tell me please?

Comment: Is it easy for you to solve this problem?Either the adapter or layout may be writed wrongly by you